# How can I organize my dll's into multiple folders under the bin directory in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

How can I take several dll's in my bin folder for my ASP.NET application organize them into seperate folders and leave them under the bin directory so that they still are readily accesible to the application as if they were in the root of the bin?  I want to reduce the monstrous list of dlls and group them into folders related to their core purpose.

Comment: Having properly named assembly filenames e.g. somenamespace.somecontext.classname helps in a way. Doesn't answer your question but this is what I do to 'manage' the long list of DLLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your application probe other directories for loading assemblies by using the web.config file and specifying a [`<probing>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx) element.  I'm unclear as to whether or not this works now with website type projects, as it did not several years ago.  It should, however, work with Web Application type projects.

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <probing privatePath="bin\subdir"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
   <system.web>
      ....
       ....
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: appeared, when I was writing my answer :)

Comment: This is the answer to my question, but I'm hoping to get feedback about the best practice for this problem.

Comment: The reason they put in this functionality is so that you can deal with situations flexibly.  While there are always best practices, there are always corner cases as well.  I'd like to see some evidence posted as to why it's bad instead of just "don't do it".

Comment: +1 That's my point.  I'm not saying this is the best way to solve my problem, but I can't see it as not being a problem.  Also maybe my approach in creating these modules is the problem and if so I'd like a strategy to consider when doing so to make their deployment less "cluttered."

Comment: can this path outside root folder of asp.net application ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. Even if it works, it will not be understood by anyone else.

If you're bothered by the number of assemblies in the bin folder, then don't look there.

Comment: We have clearly defined modules of code.  I want to use the directory structure to document in a sense what dll's are associated with a particular part of the code.  Any suggestions on this approach?

Comment: Yes, again, don't do it. That's simply not how it works. Use documents to document, but don't screw around with bin or any other _implementation_ folder.

Comment: I can see your concern, but that still doesn't address my issue of organizing all those DLL's.  If using folder's isn't the best approach what is? i.e. Naming conventions, bigger modules?

Comment: Why do you need to organize them at all in the deployment realm? Worry about organizing your projects and solutions - that's quite enough to worry about.

Comment: Organizing the project is a concern I agreee, however I want as organized of a deployment as possible.  Its hard for me to believe there isn't an approach other than "don't do it."

Comment: It's just not how ASP.NET works. You really should not try to be one of the 0.01% of people who insist on doing this.

Comment: Why do you even think anyone cares what files are in the bin folder? Nobody looks at it.

Answer (score 1):

There was an article [Moving the Code-Behind Assemblies/DLLs to a different folder than /BIN with ASP.NET 1.1](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=4d0ef4fb-f8ae-4355-a658-3c0432c98dbe)

I suppose the approach with using [assemblyBinding Element for runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twy1dw1e.aspx) can work for .NET 2.0 too

But I agree that it is not recommended...

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to organize the dlls generated by the app after compilation or the 3rd party and external dlls used by your app?

If it is the latter and you are not doing so already you can organize these into any hierarchy you choose outside the app (but inside the solution). You can then reference the dlls from there.

Trying to organize the asp.net compiler generated files feels like swimming upstream.